# Swift How to hide Carrier, Time and battery in IOS

Tags: ios, swift, statusbar

i'm getting annoying when i see that bar in top of playing video.
How can i hide\unhide status bar in viewcontroller ?

[image]

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your media player view controller:

```
override var prefersStatusBarHidden: Bool {
    return true
}
```